# Trigger an action on timeout using gnu parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

Is there a way to trigger an action (such as sending an email to an administrator) if a task spawned by gnu parallel times out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use --joblog. Exitval=-1 means timed out.

```
seq 100000 | parallel --joblog jl.log echo >> foo &
# Parse jl.log and do something with that
tail -n+1 -f jl.log | parallel  --header : echo {Exitval}
```

Comment: Can you flesh that out more?  Are you suggesting an external script that watches the log and runs an action (if so, could you give an example?) or can I use --joblog to get parallel itself to launch an action?  I'd like to have it happen right away (within a minute, say, not milliseconds) and I'm also wondering if there would be file buffering issues with an external script watching the logfile.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get a notification of your edit.  This is excellent, especially when combined with the tricks for executing a command on grep on [this unix.stackexchange thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/best-way-to-follow-a-log-and-execute-a-command-when-some-text-appears-in-the-log).  My favorite is [Jander's simple answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12100/77539) using `while read`: I.e., I'd take your last command and add `| grep --line-buffer '1' | while read exitval ; do my_command ... ; done`

Comment: For mail in particular, `| while read exitval ; do mail -s "timeout detected on ..." user@host.com,user2@host.com < /dev/null ; done`  ([examples here](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/))